# Limitation on the SELECT alias

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a query along the lines of:

```
SELECT c['name'] AS MyName
FROM c
```

The system that is going to be consuming the data requires the alias to have an application identifier before the field name, with a pipe delimiter.

So conceptually what I want is:

```
SELECT c['name'] AS [App|MyName]
FROM c
```

I don't think it is possible to use special chars in the alias, but I can't find something that says what is, and is not, possible.

Can anyone help point me at a spec of what is an acceptable format for aliases, & what chars are valid/not valid; or (even better) a way of doing this so I can avoid some slightly hacky finangling before I consume the data.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below works as expected. The aliases doesn't allow special characters except (_)

```
SELECT { "App | MyName" : c["name"] }
FROM c
```

**Output**

```
[
    {
        "$1": {
            "App | MyName": "Peter"
        }
    }
]
```

If underscore serves fine we can use as below.

```
SELECT c["name"] as App_____MyName
FROM c
```

**Output**

```
[
    {
        "App_______MyName": "Peter"
    }
]
```